# TeamCity How to Trigger a Dependent Build with a Different Logical Branch Name

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity, versioning, release-management

I have an application Project A that depends on a shared library Project B, with each project having its own VCS Root (different Git repository).

Each project versions independently, e.g. Project A could be at 1.0 while Project B is at version 2.0. We're using GitFlow as a the release model. When we make a change to both Project A and B for a release, each project would have a different release branch name. e.g. Project A: /release/1.0-rc, Project B: /release/2.0-rc.

It is possible somehow to configure Project A release build to have a Snapshot/Artifact Dependency on Project B release build?

Answer (score 1):

While adding a new Artifact dependency, it is requested to add the `Depend on`, which will be on your Project B configuration.

Then, you can specify the `Get artifacts from` to `Latest successful build`, then it will be ask if available, the Build branch to use.

The default value is `<default>` and in your case, it would be : `release/2.0-rc`.

> Note, in order to make this feature available, your VCS root should have multiple watching branches inside `Branch specification`

Comment: I want to avoid having to create or modify the build configuration for each release, which is would be required if I needed to set the Build branch to use. Essentially, I'd like to somehow dynamically set that Branch to use field (e.g. build step that determines the correct branch/version) in the Artifact Dependency.